# Escaping special character when SQL output to variable in shell script

Tags: sql, shell, db2

Trying to assign output from SQL query on an object containing special characters to a variable in shell script.

Running directly on the database:

```
db2 -x 'select count(*) from <SCHEMA>."/BIC/TEST"'

      11000
```

Yet when I include this in script I need to use double quotes as I am using variables passed into the sql. Using single quotes

```
Output=$(db2 -x 'select count(*) from ${_SCHEMA}."/BIC/TEST"')

echo -e "$Output"
```

Results in:

```
SQL20521N  Error occurred processing a conditional compilation directive near
"_". Reason code="7".  SQLSTATE=428HV
```

When I use double quotes I hit:

SQL0104N  An unexpected token "'/BIC/TEST'" was found following "ount(*)

Tried to escape the double quotes using another set of double quotes:

db2 -x 'select count(*) from ${_SCHEMA}.""/BIC/TEST""'

But this doesn't seem to work in script. It works for tables where there is no special characters/requirement to encase in quotations.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question to add which shell you are using (bash, ksh etc)

Comment: I have tried in sh & bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works fine for me, notice the escaped quotes. If it fails for you, you need to give more details of your DB2-version and the DB2-server operating system platform.

```
#!/bin/ksh

db2 connect to sample
(($? > 0 )) && print "Failed to connect to database" && exit 1

db2 -o- "drop table \"/bin/test\" "

db2 -v "create table \"/bin/test\"(a integer)"
(($? > 0 )) && print "Create table failed" && exit 1

db2 -v "insert into \"/bin/test\"(a) values(1),(2),(3),(4)"
(($? > 0 )) && print "insert rows failed" && exit 1

db2 -v describe table \"/bin/test\"

typeset -i count_rows=$(db2 -x "select count(*) from \"/bin/test\"" )
(($? > 0 )) && print "query count rows failed" && exit 1

print "\nRow count is: ${count_rows}\n"

db2 -o- connect reset
```